# Why aren’t degrees of freedom ever defined in a clear manner?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Every definition I’ve seen of degrees of freedom revolves around the number of items that are free to vary while doing a calculation. But what does that have to do with the probability beneath a t curve. Why should we care and why should the degrees of freedom affect our calculation? Why is there no simple answer? What makes a simple definition so elusive?

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)? I started writing an answer and realized I was pretty much just following their explanation.

Comment: In particular, for the $t$ distribution it comes about because $S^2$ is $\chi^2_{n-1}$ distributed, which we say because it is determined by the first $n-1$ residuals (the last residual is always the negative sum of the other $n-1$ residuals).

Comment: Maybe it's because 'degrees of freedom' DF means 'dimensionalaity' of a space or subspace, and it is convenient to talk about DFs as parameters of t, chi-squared, or F distributions without explaining derivations in terms of linear algebra. // Trivial example, an ordered list of $n$ observations $X_i$ can be considered as a vector in $n$-space. The sample mean $\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ may be used to estimate the population mean $\mu$ of the population ("using up" one DF or dimension), and the sample variance $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i = \bar X)^2$ (which "uses up" ...

Comment: ... the remaining $n-1$ dimensions) estimates the population variance $\sigma^2.$ The use of DF in the denominator of $S^2$ ensures that $E(S^2) = \sigma^2.$ Also, $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(DF = n-1).$ // The rows of a standard ANOVA table show DFs corresponding to the dimensionalities of the various mean squares. // As you begin studying statistics you can memorize the formulas for the DFs in various inferential contexts. Then wait patiently for a linear algebra based course to understand the dimensionalities of subspaces.

Comment: @BruceET Thank you for your response. I guess what I am not understanding is why is there a necessity to know the degrees of freedom in order to calculate a T distribution or any distribution, why do the number of items free to vary have an influence over the distribution we choose. How does the dimension of a random vector tie into the the probability produced by its contents. I appreciate your time in providing such a thorough answer it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, in a one-sample t test there is quite a difference between the 5% critical value if $n = 40, DF=39$ than if $n = 4, DF=3.$ For a z test the corresponding critical value is 1.96, no matter what the sample size.

Comment: @BruceET its not so much that the values are so different depending on the degrees of freedom that I am hung up on a bit, Its more why is there a need to take into account the number of degrees of freedom to begin with when calculating from a distribution. What is the rational behind why degrees of freedom are necessary to begin with or are the correct way to calculate the probability from a distribution? Thank you

Comment: Intuitively, in a t test you might think of having to 'pay a penalty' for having to estimate pop SD $\sigma$ by sample SD $S.$ The smaller the sample size, the bigger the difference between t (pop SD unknown) and z (pop SD known).